# Redirect refs from children component to the parent in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have my parent component in react js:

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const myRef = React.createRef();

    const childrenprops = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
            myRef
        });
    });
    return (
        <div>
            {childrenprops}
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

And also the children component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Child = forwardRef((props, myRef) => {
    const myRef = React.createRef();

    return (
        <div>
           ... ... ..
        </div>
    );
};

export default Child;
```

`<Child/>` component stays instead of `children` from `<MyComponent/>`. The issue is next: When I save data from child component I don't get anything in MyComponent, so I don't get the ref in parent. Question: Did I use right the `forwardref`?

Note: I have seen many examples, but on my side does not work.

Comment: React refs aren't props, per se, so you don't can't clone them with the props, but the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) confirm any refs on the original element are preserved. You also only create a single ref, so only the last component receiving the ref will be the current value of it. If you are simply trying to pass a ref to each child then you'll need to create one for each. I also don't think the `cloneElement` is necessary, but you've pretty minimal example code so your use-case context is minimal to non-existent. Ming posting a more complete example?

Comment: @DrewReese, this is my structure of the app https://codesandbox.io/s/react-editor-js-forked-tc0gh?file=/Parent.js . The idea is that i want to save data only in `save` function from Parent component, so i need  to pass a ref to the children and to save the date from editor and data data to display in save function. Could you help?  Here is a method to pass ref, but it does not work if to pass props trought children https://github.com/Jungwoo-An/react-editor-js. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Child

Each child should hold its own react reference to the editor instance. Follow this [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-editor-js#how-to-access-editor-js-instance). The child component should receive a callback prop for sending data back up to a parent.

```
const Child = ({ onSave }) => {
  const instanceRef = React.useRef(null); // <-- (1) create ref

  const onClick = async () => onSave(await instanceRef.current.save()); // <-- (4) pass the saved data to callback

  return (
    <div>
      <EditorJs
        data={.....}
        instanceRef={(instance) => (instanceRef.current = instance)} // <-- (2) save current value of editor instance
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={onClick}> // <-- (3) attach click handler
        click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

## Parent

Use the [Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) and [cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) from the React top-level API to map over the `children` prop and inject an `onSave` prop.

```
const MyComponent = ({ children }) => {
  const save = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>parent</h1>
      {Children.map(children, (child) => cloneElement(child, { onSave: save }))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then just wrap the children with the parent component.

```
class ReactEditor extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Parent>
        <Child />
      </Parent>
    );
  }
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit redirect-refs-from-children-component-to-the-parent-in-reactjs]